# SWI-Prolog predicates member and nth1 without unification?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, unification

If I use the predicates member or the nt1 in SWI-Prolog as follows:

```
?- member(X, [A]).
X = A.
```

or

```
nth1(N, [A], X).
N = 1,
A = X.
```

The interpreter unifies the variable A as X.

Is their some alternative version of this functions which does not use the unification. Means, if I call something like this:

```
?- _member(X, [A]).
```

it would give

```
 false
```

as long as the call is not

```
?- member(X, [X]).
```

which would lead to

```
true
```

And in the same way

```
_nth1(N, [A], X).
```

would give `false`

but

```
_nth1(N, [X], X).
```

would give

```
N = 1
```

Comment: you'd need to use your own unification algorithm, or assign different ground values to the different variables in your terms before calling the standard `nth1` or `member`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just need to roll your own using `==/2` instead of `=/2`:

See https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/DqhYGuEf.pl

```
is_member_of( X , [Y|_]  ) :- X == Y .
is_member_of( X , [_|Ys] ) :- is_member_of(X,Ys) .

is_nth0( N , L , E ) :- is_nth(0,L,E,N) . 

is_nth1( N , L , E ) :- is_nth(1,L,E,N) .

is_nth( N , [Y|_]  , X , N ) :- X == Y .
is_nth( I , [_|Ys] , X , N ) :- J is I+1, is_nth(J,Ys,X,N) .
```